# PHP/HTML Contact Form send to specific email based on dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, html, email, contact-form

**EDITED:**

I have a contact form using HTML/PHP. I would like users to be able to select a department from a dropdown menu, and have the email sent to just that department's email address.

**My question is:** Where in the PHP do I specify what email address the information is sent to based on the users dropdown selection. I'm assuming it's from this portion of the code:

HTML

```
            <label class="custom-select">
                <select name="department">
                    <option>Technical Issues</option>
                    <option>Charities</option>
                    <option>General Inquiries</option>
                    <option>Other</option>
                </select><span><!-- fake select handler --></span>
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="column-100">

                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="column-100 center">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" data-error="Fix errors" data-processing="Sending..." data-success="Thank you!">
            </div>
            <footer class="notification-box"></footer>
        </form>

</div>
```

PHP

```
define('FROM_EMAIL', '');

// Recipient's e-mail. To this e-mail messages will be sent.
// e.g.: john@example.com
// multiple recipients e.g.: john@example.com, andy@example.com
define('TO_EMAIL', 'info@beetheswarm.com');

/**
 * Function for sending messages. Checks input fields, prepares message and sends it.
 */
function sendMessage() {
    // Variables init
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up some logic in the PHP to change the `TO_EMAIL` variable to the appropriate email. (Line 6 of your PHP)

```
switch ( $_POST['department'] ) {
    case "Technical Issues":
        define('TO_EMAIL', 'technical@beetheswarm.com');
    break;
    case "Charities":
        define('TO_EMAIL', 'charity@beetheswarm.com');
    break;
    case "General Inquiries":
        define('TO_EMAIL', 'general@beetheswarm.com');
    break;
    default:
    case "Other":
        define('TO_EMAIL', 'info@beetheswarm.com');
    break;
}
```

Wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to fix your HTML to pass a value so we know which is selected:

```
<select name="department">
   <option value="technical">Technical Issues</option>
   <option value="charities">Charities</option>
   <option value="general">General Inquiries</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

In your form processor pull out the value:

```
$dept = $_POST['department'];
```

Then switch statement to grab the proper email:

```
switch($dept) {
   case 'technical':
       $to = "technical@company.com";
       break;

   //Rest of email cases
}

// Mail it!
$result = mail($to, $title, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I hadn't used switch statements before so thank you for explaining everything.